# Error while sending telemetry while building app in HuggingFace Spaces

Tags: deployment, huggingface, gradio

I created a gradio application to tryout basic functions yesterday and it worked fine.

Today I created a new application that will differentiate between  Mug and a glass. I performed the same steps I used yesterday to create a Gradio app and host it on HuggingFace spaces. But I am getting this error.

`Error while sending telemetry: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.gradio.app', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gradio-launched-telemetry/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('\<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb286bb7e80\>: Failed to establish a new connection: \[Errno -3\] Temporary failure in name resolution'))`

I can't find any resolution online, all help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I didn't exactly try anything all I did was compared the code I have today with the one I used yesterday. On my localhost the application is working fine. The issue happens during building the application in huggingface spaces.

Edit: I rebooted the HuggingFace Space the next day, now it is working fine.